# Checkers Game ... check_move function?

Tags: c++

Trying to run this program but having understanding the check_move function. I believe it was made to make sure there isn't a board piece there already...making move illegal. 
It was declared as a function but however I cannot find the definition/implementation. Program tries to call the function using 
    "while (check_move() == false)" in the void input(). A bit lost....can someone help?

```
//This is a 2 player checker game
//
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

char board[8][8] =
{
    {' ', 'b', ' ', 'b', ' ', 'b', ' ', 'b'},
    {'b', ' ', 'b', ' ', 'b', ' ', 'b', ' '},
    {' ', 'b', ' ', 'b', ' ', 'b', ' ', 'b'},
    {' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '},
    {' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '},
    {'r', ' ', 'r', ' ', 'r', ' ', 'r', ' '},
    {' ', 'r', ' ', 'r', ' ', 'r', ' ', 'r'},
    {'r', ' ', 'r', ' ', 'r', ' ', 'r', ' '},
};

char turn = 'B';
bool leap;
bool game_running = true;
int row1, row2, column1, column2;

void display_board();// 
void input();//
bool check_move();//where is the 
void move();
void do_leap();
void king();
void game_over();

int main()
{
    cout << "***CHECKER GAME***\n";
    cout << "Player 1 [b]\n";
    cout << "Player 2 [r]\n\n";
    cout << "Multiple leaps are supported.\n";
    cout << "A capital letter represents a king piece.\n";
    cout << "NOTE: Rows and columns are counted starting from 0, not 1.\n";
    cout << "<------COLUMNS------>\n";
    cout << "^\n";
    cout << "|\n";
    cout << "|\n";
    cout << "|\n";
    cout << "ROWS\n";
    cout << "|\n";
    cout << "|\n";
    cout << "|\n";
    cout << "v\n\n";
    cout << "NOTE: Resize your console screen so that this line fits on the screen:\n";
    cout << "_____________________________________________________________________________________\n\n";
    cout << "Press enter to begin...";
    cin.get();//This waits for the user to press enter before continuing

    while (game_running)//game_running was initialzed to true so will run
    {
        display_board();//function is called to display board

        if (turn == 'B')//was initialzed to 'B'line 19
        {
            cout << "--Player 1 [B]--\n";//says player 1 turn
        }
        else if (turn == 'R')
        {
            cout << "--Player 2 [R]--\n";
        }
        //funcitons called
        input();
        move();
        king();
        game_over();
    }

    if (turn == 'B')
    {
        cout << endl << endl << "Player 2 [Red] wins!!!\n";
    }
    else if (turn == 'R')
    {
        cout << endl << endl << "Player 1 [Black] wins!!!\n";
    }

    cout << "GAME OVER!\n";
}

void display_board()//board displayed is similar to tic tac toe except its bigger, has empty spaces
{
    cout << "==================================================================================\n\n\n\n";
    cout << "       0         1         2         3         4         5         6         7     \n";
    cout << "  _________________________________________________________________________________\n";
    cout << "  |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |\n";
    cout << "  |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |\n";
    cout << "0 |    " << board[0][0] << "    |    " << board[0][1] << "    |    " << board[0][2] << "    |    "  << board[0][3] << "    |    " << board[0][4] << "    |    " << board[0][5] << "    |    " << board[0][6] << "    |    " << board[0][7] << "    |\n";
    cout << "  |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |\n";
    cout << "  |_________|_________|_________|_________|_________|_________|_________|_________|\n";
    cout << "  |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |\n";
    cout << "  |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |\n";
    cout << "1 |    " << board[1][0] << "    |    " << board[1][1] << "    |    " << board[1][2] << "    |    "  << board[1][3] << "    |    " << board[1][4] << "    |    " << board[1][5] << "    |    " << board[1][6] << "    |    " << board[1][7] << "    |\n";
    cout << "  |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |\n";
    cout << "  |_________|_________|_________|_________|_________|_________|_________|_________|\n";
    cout << "  |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |\n";
    cout << "  |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |\n";
    cout << "2 |    " << board[2][0] << "    |    " << board[2][1] << "    |    " << board[2][2] << "    |    "  << board[2][3] << "    |    " << board[2][4] << "    |    " << board[2][5] << "    |    " << board[2][6] << "    |    " << board[2][7] << "    |\n";
    cout << "  |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |\n";
    cout << "  |_________|_________|_________|_________|_________|_________|_________|_________|\n";
    cout << "  |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |\n";
    cout << "  |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |\n";
    cout << "3 |    " << board[3][0] << "    |    " << board[3][1] << "    |    " << board[3][2] << "    |    "  << board[3][3] << "    |    " << board[3][4] << "    |    " << board[3][5] << "    |    " << board[3][6] << "    |    " << board[3][7] << "    |\n";
    cout << "  |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |\n";
    cout << "  |_________|_________|_________|_________|_________|_________|_________|_________|\n";
    cout << "  |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |\n";
    cout << "  |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |\n";
    cout << "4 |    " << board[4][0] << "    |    " << board[4][1] << "    |    " << board[4][2] << "    |    "  << board[4][3] << "    |    " << board[4][4] << "    |    " << board[4][5] << "    |    " << board[4][6] << "    |    " << board[4][7] << "    |\n";
    cout << "  |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |\n";
    cout << "  |_________|_________|_________|_________|_________|_________|_________|_________|\n";
    cout << "  |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |\n";
    cout << "  |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |\n";
    cout << "5 |    " << board[5][0] << "    |    " << board[5][1] << "    |    " << board[5][2] << "    |    "  << board[5][3] << "    |    " << board[5][4] << "    |    " << board[5][5] << "    |    " << board[5][6] << "    |    " << board[5][7] << "    |\n";
    cout << "  |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |\n";
    cout << "  |_________|_________|_________|_________|_________|_________|_________|_________|\n";
    cout << "  |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |\n";
    cout << "  |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |\n";
    cout << "6 |    " << board[6][0] << "    |    " << board[6][1] << "    |    " << board[6][2] << "    |    "  << board[6][3] << "    |    " << board[6][4] << "    |    " << board[6][5] << "    |    " << board[6][6] << "    |    " << board[6][7] << "    |\n";
    cout << "  |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |\n";
    cout << "  |_________|_________|_________|_________|_________|_________|_________|_________|\n";
    cout << "  |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |\n";
    cout << "  |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |\n";
    cout << "7 |    " << board[7][0] << "    |    " << board[7][1] << "    |    " << board[7][2] << "    |    "  << board[7][3] << "    |    " << board[7][4] << "    |    " << board[7][5] << "    |    " << board[7][6] << "    |    " << board[7][7] << "    |\n";
    cout << "  |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |\n";
    cout << "  |_________|_________|_________|_________|_________|_________|_________|_________|\n";
}

void input()//asks player first to CHOOSE their piece using row and column # for exact location, then to MOVE using same concept
{
    cout << "Move piece\n";
    cout << "Row: ";
    cin >> row1;//
    cout << "Column: ";
    cin >> column1;

    while (row1 < 0 || row1 > 7 || column1 < 0 || column1 > 7)//CHOOSE PIECE ...makes sure the input(Chosen piece) is within range
    {
        cout << "Incorrect input. Enter numbers between 0 and 7.\n";//runs if input out of range
        cout << "Move piece\n";
        cout << "Row: ";
        cin >> row1;//allows another chance to enter input 
        cout << "Column: ";
        cin >> column1;
    }

    cout << "To box\n";//allows to MOVE to another location based on row and column
    cout << "Row: ";
    cin >> row2;
    cout << "Column: ";
    cin >> column2;

    while (row2 < 0 || row2 > 7 || column2 < 0 || column2 > 7)//MOVE PIECE...makes sure the move is legal
    {
        cout << "Incorrect input. Enter numbers between 0 and 7.\n";
        cout << "To box\n";
        cout << "Row: ";
        cin >> row2;
        cout << "Column: ";
        cin >> column2;
    }

    while (check_move() == false)//check_move is called....and checks if it is false
    {
        cout << "ILLEGAL MOVE!!\n";
        input();//input function starts again at line 133
    }
}



void move()
{
    bool king_piece = false;

    if (board[row1][column1] == 'B' || board[row1][column1] == 'R')
    {
        king_piece = true;
    }

    board[row1][column1] = ' ';

    if (turn == 'B')
    {
        if (king_piece == false)
        {
            board[row2][column2] = 'b';
        }
        else if (king_piece == true)
        {
            board[row2][column2] = 'B';
        }

        turn = 'R';
    }
    else if (turn == 'R')
    {
        if (king_piece == false)
        {
            board[row2][column2] = 'r';
        }
        else if (king_piece == true)
        {
            board[row2][column2] = 'R';
        }

        turn = 'B';
    }

    if (leap == true)
    {
        do_leap();
    }
}

void do_leap()
{
    char answer;

    //It removes the checker piece after leap.
    if (row2 > row1 && column2 > column1)
    {
        board[row2 - 1][column2 - 1] = ' ';
    }
    else if (row2 > row1 && column2 < column1)
    {
        board[row2 - 1][column2 + 1] = ' ';
    }
    else if (row2 < row1 && column2 > column1)
    {
        board[row2 + 1][column2 - 1] = ' ';
    }
    else if (row2 < row1 && column2 < column1)
    {
        board[row2 + 1][column2 + 1] = ' ';
    }

    display_board();//It displays the board after the changes

    //It asks if the user wants to leap again.
    do
    {
        cout << "You just leaped once. Do you want to do a second leap IF YOU CAN? (y/n): ";
        cin >> answer;
    }
    while (answer != 'Y' && answer != 'y' && answer != 'N' && answer != 'n');

    if (answer == 'y' || answer == 'Y')
    {
        row1 = row2;
        column1 = column2;
        cout << "Leap piece: row: " << row1 << ", column: " << column1 << endl;
        cout << "To box\n";
        cout << "row: ";
        cin >> row2;
        cout << "column: ";
        cin >> column2;

        while (row2 < 0 || row2 > 7 || column2 < 0 || column2 > 7)
        {
            cout << "Incorrect input. Enter numbers between 0 and 7.\n";
            cout << "To box\n";
            cout << "Row: ";
            cin >> row2;
            cout << "Column: ";
            cin >> bool check_move()

            {
                //it checks if a non-king piece is moving backwards.
                if (board[row1][column1] != 'B' && board[row1][column1] != 'R')
                {
                    if ((turn == 'B' && row2 < row1) || (turn == 'R' && row2 > row1))
                    {
                        leap = false;
                        return false;
                    }
                }

                //It checks if the location the piece is moving to is already taken.
                if (board[row2][column2] != ' ')
                {
                    leap = false;
                    return false;
                }

                //It checks if location entered by the user contains a piece to be moved.
                if (board[row1][column1] == ' ')
                {
                    leap = false;
                    return false;
                }

                //It checks if the piece isn't moving diagonally.
                if (column1 == column2 || row1 == row2)
                {
                    leap = false;
                    return false;
                }

                //It checks if the piece is moving by more than 1 column and only 1 row
                if ((column2 > column1 + 1 || column2 < column1 - 1) && (row2 == row1 +1 || row2 == row1 - 1))
                {
                    leap = false;
                    return false;
                }

                //It checks if the piece is leaping.
                if (row2 > row1 + 1 || row2 < row1 - 1)
                {
                    //It checks if the piece is leaping too far.
                    if (row2 > row1 + 2 || row2 < row1 - 2)
                    {
                        leap = false;
                        return false;
                    }

                    //It checks if the piece isn't moving by exactly 2 columns
                    if (column2 != column1 + 2 && column2 != column1 - 2)
                    {
                        leap = false;
                        return false;
                    }

                    //It checks if the piece is leaping over another piece.
                    if (row2 > row1 && column2 > column1)
                    {
                        if (board[row2 - 1][column2 - 1] == ' ')
                        {
                            leap = false;
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (row2 > row1 && column2 < column1)
                    {
                        if (board[row2 - 1][column2 + 1] == ' ')
                        {
                            leap = false;
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (row2 < row1 && column2 > column1)
                    {
                        if (board[row2 + 1][column2 - 1] == ' ')
                        {
                            leap = false;
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (row2 < row1 && column2 < column1)
                    {
                        if (board[row2 + 1][column2 + 1] == ' ')
                        {
                            leap = false;
                            return false;
                        }
                    }

                    leap = true;
                    return true;
                }

                leap = false;
                return true;
            } column2;
        }
    }

        if (turn == 'B')
        {
            turn = 'R';
        }
        else if (turn == 'R')
        {
            turn = 'B';
        }

        check_move();

        if (leap == false)
        {
            cout << "INVALID LEAP!!\n";

            if (turn == 'B')
            {
                turn = 'R';
            }
            else if (turn == 'R')
            {
                turn = 'B';
            }
        }
        else if (leap == true)
        {
            move();
        }
    }
}

void king()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        if (board[0][i] == 'r')
        {
            board[0][i] = 'R';
        }

        if (board[7][i] == 'b')
        {
            board[7][i] = 'B';
        }
    }
}

void game_over()
{
    int counter = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
        {
            if (board[i][j] != ' ')
            {
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }

    if (counter > 1)
    {
        game_running = true;
    }
    else if (counter == 1)
    {
        game_running = false;
    }
}
}   



/*

 ISSUE:

 -check_move is declared as s function but has no def/implementation
 -Could it be intended to be declared as a variable??
```

Comment: Please, post a **minimal** example of your problem, not the entire program.

Comment: It looks like the method is indeed missing. Are you sure you got all the code?

Answer (score 0):

```
bool check_move();
```

is a [forward declaration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration) the function must be defined in some other file. 
You should know where the code is from and ask for the complete source.

Answer (score 0):

In the middle of the `do_leap` function we see:

```
 cout << "Column: ";
 cin >> bool check_move()
 {
        //it checks if a non-king piece is moving backwards.
        if (board[row1][column1] != 'B' && board[row1][column1] != 'R')
        {
```

The second line of this quote is a syntax error; it looks like someone has copy-pasted the `check_move` function into the middle of the `do_leap` function (perhaps a misclick in an editor with mouse copy-paste functionality).

There's nothing apparent after the misplaced `check_move` function that would fit after `cin >>` , so it looks like this paste operation has actually "cut" out some of the original code.  You will need to find the original code from another source (or if you're feeling brave, extricate `check_move` and try to rewrite the missing parts of `do_leap`).

Answer (score 0):

This source code is apparently corrupted.

The `check_move` function is declared in the middle of another function...

```
        cout << "Column: ";
        cin >> bool check_move()
        {
           ...
```

this is not valid C++.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where you got your source, but the full source of the program can be found here with the missing method:

http://runnable.com/U-_XgNndbURbbgx-/c%2B%2B-checkers-game

```
bool check_move()
{
    //it checks if a non-king piece is moving backwards.
    if (board[row1][column1] != 'B' && board[row1][column1] != 'R')
    {
        if ((turn == 'B' && row2 < row1) || (turn == 'R' && row2 > row1))
        {
            leap = false;
            return false;
        }
    }

    //It checks if the location the piece is moving to is already taken.
    if (board[row2][column2] != ' ')
    {
        leap = false;
        return false;
    }

    //It checks if location entered by the user contains a piece to be moved.
    if (board[row1][column1] == ' ')
    {
        leap = false;
        return false;
    }

    //It checks if the piece isn't moving diagonally.
    if (column1 == column2 || row1 == row2)
    {
        leap = false;
        return false;
    }

    //It checks if the piece is moving by more than 1 column and only 1 row
    if ((column2 > column1 + 1 || column2 < column1 - 1) && (row2 == row1 +1 || row2 == row1 - 1))
    {
        leap = false;
        return false;
    }

    //It checks if the piece is leaping.
    if (row2 > row1 + 1 || row2 < row1 - 1)
    {
        //It checks if the piece is leaping too far.
        if (row2 > row1 + 2 || row2 < row1 - 2)
        {
            leap = false;
            return false;
        }

        //It checks if the piece isn't moving by exactly 2 columns
        if (column2 != column1 + 2 && column2 != column1 - 2)
        {
            leap = false;
            return false;
        }

        //It checks if the piece is leaping over another piece.
        if (row2 > row1 && column2 > column1)
        {
            if (board[row2 - 1][column2 - 1] == ' ')
            {
                leap = false;
                return false;
            }
        }
        else if (row2 > row1 && column2 < column1)
        {
            if (board[row2 - 1][column2 + 1] == ' ')
            {
                leap = false;
                return false;
            }
        }
        else if (row2 < row1 && column2 > column1)
        {
            if (board[row2 + 1][column2 - 1] == ' ')
            {
                leap = false;
                return false;
            }
        }
        else if (row2 < row1 && column2 < column1)
        {
            if (board[row2 + 1][column2 + 1] == ' ')
            {
                leap = false;
                return false;
            }
        }

        leap = true;
        return true;
    }

    leap = false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I selected and moved piece based on row/column but keeps reading "ILLEGAL MOVE"...